Set compiler flag when installing with vcpkg
I am trying to install pugixml using vcpkg and linking to it using cmake. I want to use it on windows and therefor want to use wchar_t instead of char. I know that pugixml has a compiler flag for this (-DPUGIXML_WCHAR_MODE), since I have managed to use it using FetchContent previously.
However, when installing and linking to pugixml which was installed using vcpkg, I receive error:
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
The error is (most likely) appearing because there is a mismatch between my project and the installed project from vcpkg.
I could successfully build pugixml with my project when loading and linking to it using FetchContent, and passing my own compiler flags (-DPUGIXML_WCHAR_MODE).
My question is, is it possible to pass compiler flags to vcpkg when installing a package?

There isn't really an easy way -- there's some hackiness involving "triplet overlays", sure, but it would be better for everyone to ask them to add a feature to the pugixml that sets the wchar mode one way or another. Then you can depend on that feature.

Submit a PR to revise the port on GitHub which updates the port-revision, adds the feature you need, and that should be all to need to do.

@ChuckWalbourn Will do!
